# rake db:migrate error (Migrations are pending)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I have been searching for a solution to my problem and haven't had any luck. I am a beginner following a tutorial and I reached a point where I had to run the command 'rake db:migrate' and keep getting an error.

```
$ rake db:migrate
== 20160927120721 CreateTodoItems: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:todo_items)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `refrences' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x0055d8b19b8298>
Did you mean?  references
/home/paul/todo/db/migrate/20160927120721_create_todo_items.rb:5:in `block in change'
/home/paul/todo/db/migrate/20160927120721_create_todo_items.rb:3:in `change'
NoMethodError: undefined method `refrences' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x0055d8b19b8298>
Did you mean?  references
/home/paul/todo/db/migrate/20160927120721_create_todo_items.rb:5:in `block in change'
/home/paul/todo/db/migrate/20160927120721_create_todo_items.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have tried to reset the rake with 'rake db:reset' but it tells me that there is a pending migration and to try 'rake db:migrate'. I also tried 'rake db:drop' 'gem update rake' 'bundle update rake' 'bunlde exec rake db:migrate' and still no luck. Can someone assist me with this? I am very new to all of this so if there's anything more I can post please let me know so I can continue to grow and learn! Thanks in advance!!

Ubuntu 16.04LTS 
Rails 4.2.6
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: change `refrences` to `references` just like the suggestion rails gives you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `refrences` in `20160927120721_create_todo_items.rb` on line 5 to valid **`references`** as your errors says.

Always carefully read Rails's exceptions - they are usually informative.

Comment: @paulkiio make sure to accept the answer (checkmark on the left) if this solved your issue. You can accept only one answer per question.

Answer (score 2):

In your 20160927120721_create_todo_items.rb file you have mistype **refrences**, change it to **references**